# How to add Separator to MainMenu in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, mainmenu

I am currently learning and practicing `Windows Forms` with .Net 4.8. I am currently creating a `MainMenu` through C# as there is no option available for `MainMenu`. There are only a few different `MenuItems`. I want to add a separator to the `MainMenu`. I've searched all the web for separator and messed around with the class to find if there is any `function` or `property` that can do for me. I even looked for a Separator class but I only found `ToolStripSeparator`. How can I do that?

**Note:** I have tried using `MenuStrip` but I don't want the menu to look like that. I want it to look like the one we code with `Windows API`, a very simple one.

If anyone wants the code, here it is :-

```cs
public void CreateMyMainMenu()
{
   MainMenu mainMenu1 = new MainMenu();

   MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
   MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem();

   menuItem1.Text = "File";
   menuItem2.Text = "Edit";

   mainMenu1.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
   mainMenu1.MenuItems.Add(menuItem2);
   
   Menu = mainMenu1;   
}
```

This example and some documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Don't use the (deprecated) MainMenu class, use a MenuStrip class instead. The Separator is a standard object that you add the same way you add other parts of a Menu.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your suggestion. But as I said, I don't want my menu to look like that with `MenuStrip`, I want it to be simple. How do we add separator, with `ToolStripSeparator`?

Comment: What does *simple* mean? You can customize the appearance of menus in a MenuStrip as you like, similar to a (already mentioned, deprecated, not portable) MainMenu. -- A Separator in the old MainMenu is added using a hyphen: `-` as the menu text. -- I suggest you get used to the MenuStrip and learn how to customize it. If /when you'll need to port the app to .Net 5+, you'll have to replace MainMenus with MenuStrips anyway.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your reply, I did work with `MenuStrip` and managed to get looking the way I wanted though it is very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a hyphen will work for you just fine:

```
mainMenu1.MenuItems.Add("-");
```

Also, I do recommend to use a MenuStrip instead of a MainMenu, since this class has been deprecated and removed from the .Net Core and .Net 5.0+ versions of WinForms.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I worked with `MenuStrip` and it looks the way I wanted though it is very complicated. Even I am 14, coding stuff just like you.

Comment: Oh cool! I am happy to meet someone like me and I hope you grow to build really good applications, websites and games in the future. :)